# Query in jupyter notebook error when querying with WHERE and " ' "

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do a query in jupyter notebook and save it in pandas dataframe.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-P2RVLB2\RENO_DATACAMP;'
                      'Database=Introduction_to_SQL_Server;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
# SELECT the country column FROM the eurovision table
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT description, event_year from Introduction_to_SQL_Server.dbo.grid WHERE description ='Vandalism';',conn)
print(sql_query)
print(type(sql_query))
```

and its shows error like this :

```
File "<ipython-input-69-0c8fd6cbc2be>", line 9
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT description, event_year from Introduction_to_SQL_Server.dbo.grid WHERE description ='Vandalism';',conn)
                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me solve this error, thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes for the entire query, and single quotes for inside the query.

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT description, event_year from Introduction_to_SQL_Server.dbo.grid WHERE description ='Vandalism'",conn)
```

Also I believe the semicolon is not necessary at the end of the query

Comment: Hey its work! thanks mitch, I'm just learning about sql and python, and I'm just getting to know how to use double and single quotes. and yes, semicolon is not needed